# How to specify colors manually in ggplot2 within a for loop?

Tags: r

I am building some code to plot energy supply vs. energy demand for bird populations with user-defined foraging guilds. I don't know in advance how many guilds a user will specify, and I need to create guild-specific plots. I would like to be able to specify the colors of the lines for energy supply and demand. Here's my data:

```
guilds <- c("ducks","geese") #I have 2 foraging guilds
dayz <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6) #The plot will span 6 days
guild1_supply <- c(100,120,150,130,110,70) #energy available to guild 1
guild2_supply <- c(70,90,110,120,100,80) #energy available to guild 2
supply_by_guild <- cbind(guild1_supply,guild2_supply)
guild1_demand <- c(10,80,120,130,70,20) #energy demand for guild 1
guild2_demand <- c(5,45,75,60,30,0) #energy demand for guild 2
demand_by_guild <- cbind(guild1_demand,guild2_demand)
setwd("C:/Users/XXX) #Set working directory for figure output
```

Now I create guild-specific plots in a for loop.

```
for (i in 1:length(guilds)) { # use a for loop to create data frames
temp <- data.frame(cbind(dayz,supply_by_guild[,i],demand_by_guild[,i]))
names(temp)[2] <- "Food Energy Supply" # rename variable
names(temp)[3] <- "Food Energy Demand" # rename variable
temp <- melt(temp, id.vars = c("dayz")) # melt data frame to long format
names(temp)[2] <- "Legend" # rename variable
names(temp)[3] <- "energy" # rename variable
jpeg(paste("Fig",i+4,".jpg",sep=""),width=2000, height=1000, res=300)
print(ggplot(data=temp, aes(x=dayz, y=energy,group=Legend, color=Legend)) + geom_line() + xlab("Day") + ylab(paste("Energy   (",energy_unit,")",sep="")) + ggtitle(paste("Figure ",i+4,". Daily Food Energy Supply and Demand: ",guilds[i],sep=""))) 
dev.off()
}
```

This above code works, but when I try to manually specify the colors of the lines by adding `+ scale_color_manual(values=c("cyan4", "orangered1"))`, I get the error "non-numeric argument to binary operator." Any help much appreciated.

Comment: It seems to work for me. Your `for` loop is a bit confusing a lot going on. Maybe that's whats causing problems, you could try splitting it apart, maybe that would help nail down the problem code

Comment: a. Just use `labs` instead of renaming variables. b. Use `ggsave` instead of `jpeg`. c. Don't use `for` loops to build data.frames.

Comment: Thanks @alistaire. I ended up using a for loop to save individual data frames for each guild to a list. Then I used another for loop to create the guild-specific plots, and my issue with specifying colors manually went away. ggsave was helpful also.